# Android SearchDialog - Disable spell-check/suggestions?

Tags: android, android-searchmanager

I'm using a [SearchDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#SearchDialog) in my Android app. Is there any way to force-disable the autocompletion/spell-checker/suggestions? My search really doesn't need it - most of the words my users will be searching for don't exist in a dictionary.

I couldn't find an answer on google or stackoverflow.

In my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
</activity>
```

Then I'm calling `onSearchRequested()`